# deserialize json to object in netstandard1.0

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, .net-standard, httpresponsemessage

I am trying to serialize a string that is returned from a http response and I am using netstandard1.0. Not a lot of serializing functions work in this framework, but I finally found a working function. Here is my code so far:

```
HttpResponseMessage Response = // initialized else where
var jsonTask = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (!jsonTask.IsCompleted) jsonTask.RunSynchronously();
string json = jsonTask.Result;
Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
```

However this does not deserialize I get from the http response. It throws an error that the `DeserializeObject` function is looking for a different format. When I run `Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, I get the result in the following format.

"[{\"key\":\"Password\",\"errors\":[\"The Password field is required.\"]},{\"key\":\"UserName\",\"errors\":[\"The UserName field is required.\"]},{\"key\":\"OrganizationUserName\",\"errors\":[\"The OrganizationUserName field is required.\"]}]"

Does anyone know how to deserialize this format?

Comment: 1)  Your outermost JSON container is an array so you must deserialize it as some sort of collection, e.g. `List<MyModel>`.  2) What is `MyModel`?  How did you generate it?

Comment: Thanks. It was the list issue. Regarding your second question, I put code from several places together to shorten the question. Basically `MyModel` is a generic type that is provided when the function is called. I am planning to have it be the same object passed by my web api

Comment: also could you post the list as an answer so i can mark it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your `MyModel` as follows:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public List<string> errors { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize as follows:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(json);
```

Notes:

- I generated the c# definition for `MyModel` by uploading your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/.
- The reason for the exception you are seeing trying to deserialize directly to `MyModel` is that your outer JSON container is an array, not an object.   As explained in the [standard](http://www.json.org/), JSON has two types of container:

  1. An array which is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
  2. An object which is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace).

  In the Json.NET **[Serialization Guide: IEnumerable, Lists, and Arrays](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Lists)** it is explained that JSON arrays are converted from and to .Net types implementing `IEnumerable`.  So that's what you need to do.
- If you know the array will contain no more than one element, you can use [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract that single element:

  ```
  Data = list.SingleOrDefault();
  ```

  However, in the example included in you question, the outer array has 3 items, so this is not appropriate.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iAH8m7).